# CSS Accordion issue along with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is my accordion and I am stuck at the stage where I cannot figure out how to dynamically select each accordion to open one at a time instead of making them open all at once. As of now, no matter which one I select, they end up opening. I appreciate to see a cool trick so that I can only see one at a time.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that every time one section opens up, I want others section to be closed.

```js
// Accordions
const accordions = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion");
const lists = document.querySelectorAll("ul");

function activate(e) {
  accordions.forEach(acc => acc.classList.toggle("active"));
  lists.forEach(list => list.classList.toggle("show"));
}

accordions.forEach(acc => acc.addEventListener("click", activate));
```

```css
.footer {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 1.3rem;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
  
  p {
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  }
  
.footer-cols {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
}

.accordion::after {
  content: "\002B";
  color: #999;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
          
.active::after {
  content: "\2212";
}
        
        ul {
          border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
          max-height: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          }
          .show {
            max-height: initial;
          }
          li {
            line-height: 1.9;
            padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
            list-style:none;
          }
          a {
            color: #999;
            font-size: 0.9rem;
            text-decoration:none;
          }
```

```html
    <footer class="footer">
      <p>Questions? Call 1-866-579-7172</p>
      <div class="footer-cols">
        <div class="accordion_section">
          <h3 class="accordion">FAQ</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Investor Relations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ways To Watch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Corporate Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Netflix Originals</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion_section">
          <h3 class="accordion">Help Center</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Terms Of Use</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion_section">
          <h3 class="accordion">Account</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Redeem Gift Cards</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion_section">
          <h3 class="accordion">Media Center</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Buy Gift Cards</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cookie Preferences</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Legal Notices</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: you need to remove the loops in the activate method and use current target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some changes to your js, and added the show class to the ul element of clicked element.

```js
// Accordions
const accordions = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion");
const lists = document.querySelectorAll("ul");

for(let element of accordions){
 element.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      if(element.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('show')){
    element.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show')
      element.classList.remove('active')
    return false;
  }
      accordions.forEach((el) => {
        el.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show')
        el.classList.remove('active')
      })
          element.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show')
          element.classList.add('active')
      })
    }
```

```css
.footer {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 1.3rem;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
  
  p {
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  }
  
.footer-cols {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
}

.accordion::after {
  content: "\002B";
  color: #999;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
          
.active::after {
  content: "\2212";
}
        
        ul {
          border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
          max-height: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          }
          .show {
            max-height: initial;
          }
          li {
            line-height: 1.9;
            padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
            list-style:none;
          }
          a {
            color: #999;
            font-size: 0.9rem;
            text-decoration:none;
          }
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
      <p>Questions? Call 1-866-579-7172</p>
      <div class="footer-cols">
        <div class="accordion_section">
          <h3 class="accordion">FAQ</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Investor Relations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ways To Watch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Corporate Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Netflix Originals</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion_section">
          <h3 class="accordion">Help Center</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Terms Of Use</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion_section">
          <h3 class="accordion">Account</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Redeem Gift Cards</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion_section">
          <h3 class="accordion">Media Center</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Buy Gift Cards</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cookie Preferences</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Legal Notices</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Oh my thank you. I forgot to mention that every time one section opens up, I want others section to be closed...Sorry!

Comment: @YongJunJung Updated

Comment: @AdityaThakur There is a bug, you didn't take care of the active state of the icon

Comment: @karthick Sorry my bad, didn't notice, (fixed)

Answer (score 1):

Change your activate method, lose the loop. You already have the event use the target element of that

```
function activate(e) {      
  let currentAccordion = e.currentTarget;
  let currentList = currentAccordion.nextElementSibling;
  closeOthers(currentAccordion, currentList );
  currentAccordion.classList.toggle("active");
  currentList.classList.toggle("show");
}

function closeOthers(currentAcc, currentList){
  accordions.forEach(acc => {
    if(currentAcc != acc) acc.classList.remove("active")
    var list = acc.nextElementSibling;
    if(currentList != list) list.classList.remove("show")
  });
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that every time one section opens up, I want others section to be closed...

Comment: @YongJunJung Updated with closing others

Comment: I just found out that the state of icon on your code also does not work :(

Comment: it does, you can see here that the icon changes based on the action performed https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/odk8Lecr/

Comment: Oh my bad, I did not type properly. One final question! I want to apply a transition; I tried to apply on ul element using "transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out" but it does not work...Why is that?

Comment: for that to work your max-height or height needs to be a value. Browsers doesn't honor auto / initial

Comment: @YongJunJung It would be a better idea to use, `transform: scale()` instead of height for transitions.

Comment: I tried transform scale but it just made everything bigger...any tips?